# Can you re merchandise categories through import on CE 2.2?

Tags: category, magento2.2, import

We are on Magento 2.2 CE and so have no way of merchandising categories without going into the categories and re merchandising by changing their numbers manually. Is there a way to change the ranking of the products within a category via import?

Many thanks in advance